# Как открывать директорию через программу (тотал коммандер) по умолчанию?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система, totalcommander

У меня есть тотал коммандер, но постоянно открывать его, а потом через него открывать файлы как-то не очень круто. Можно ли как-то открывать файлы через тотал коммандер по умолчанию? Как, например, есть .png, у него в свойствах можно выбрать программу по умолчанию. А вот у файлов нет такого и мне интересно, как можно обыграть этот вопрос

ПРОСЬБА: не писать "гениальные" ответы из разряда "пользуйтесь только тоталом". У меня стоит вопрос о том, что открывать директории через тотал коммандер. Чтобы при двойном клике на папку открывался тотал коммандер с этим файлом. Если такой возможности нет - напишите нет, в чём ваша проблема? Мне просто кажется, что я где-то видел эту настройку, а щас найти уже не могу

Comment: Открыть с помощью - Выбрать программу - В открывшемся окне поставить галочку у "Использовать выбранную программу для всех файлов этого типа" - Через кнопку "Обзор" найти exe'шник тотал коммандера на компе и принять. Мб это вам надо

Comment: Нет там Открыть с помощью (кроме vs code). Я говорю про файл, как про директорию

Comment: Так и работайте всё время в тотале, а не во всяких там проводниках.

Comment: Мне иногда удобнее открыть директорию через рабочий стол, а потом через тотал коммандер перемещать всё в другие директории